# Interface gráfica dinâmica em Java

Tags: java, swing

Preciso de criar algo deste gênero:

[image: IMG]

[image: img]

Normalmente costumo fazer as GUI's com ajuda do IDE mas neste caso não posso(acho eu), porque preciso que a GUI se repita um numero de vezes indefinido, dependendo do utilizador em questão.

**Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Como lido com os problemas dos tamanhos como posições dos componentes? Neste caso acho que só vou precisar de mostrar valores mas como faço o `SETtext/GETtext` dos valores dos componentes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ideal é criar listas e colocar esses componentes para que possa acessá-las com facilidade posteriormente. E para a questão do layout recomendo usar o emcapsulamento em caixas (Box) pois pode criar duas verticais e uma horizontal para
manter o layout de uma forma organizada. (Claro que precisará de ajustes para que o programa fique *"bonito"*. Mas, é só fazer algumas contas e posicionar os elementos e não terá erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GuiApp1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GuiApp1();
    }

    public GuiApp1()
    {
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Example GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(300,250);
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Box caixaVertical = Box.createVerticalBox();

        List<JLabel> labelLista = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        List<JTextField> inputLista = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            Box caixaHorizontal = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label" + i + "         ");
            JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
            labelLista.add(label);
            inputLista.add(input);
            caixaHorizontal.add(label);
            caixaHorizontal.add(input);
            caixaVertical.add(caixaHorizontal);
        }
        guiFrame.add(caixaVertical);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Nota 1 : eu não me preocupei com a estética desse programa**

Nota 2: eu particularmente prefiro programar boa parte da Interface sempre na mão.

(mas uso um programa de edição de imagens para visualizar o posicionamento desejado i.e photoshop/ paintshop etc)

Comment: **Desculpa só para esclarecer** mas eu não quero que os componentes se repitam, eu quero é que toda a estrutura se repita, mas quanto aos componentes percebi, tentar usar alguma estrutura que os organize logo, para não estar a definir a posição de componente por componente. Mas não percebi é como aceder a eles, podes postar um exemplo?

Comment: Não estava a pensar direito, quanto a estrutura(panel) se repetir é bastante fácil, criei uma função que me devolve um panel, depois é só adicionar ao frame OK, mas estou com problemas para aceder aos componentes, eu precebi a logica das listas mas no teu exemplo é facil so estas a usar label e textbox mas eu queria mais componentes nao conheces nenhuma maneira melhor para o fazer?

Comment: @jsantos1991 como quer repetir algo padronizado, crie uma classe que herde da classe `JPanel` e crie métodos públicos para acessar o que precisa de cada componente. (Repare que disse o que precisa e não os componentes). Por exemplo na sua classe `MeuPanel` crie um setCheckBox1() e e trabalhe e retorne diretamente o valor a partir do mesmo. Depois faça uma lista com esses componentes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso que estava a pensar, quando fiz a pergunta estava mesmo confuso quanto ao GUI dinâmico, por ser dinâmico e principalmente pela minha falta de experiência agora já estou bem mais esclarecido... Obrigado